# Why am i getting list index out of range when i remove an item from the list?

Tags: python

Im creating a game where i have roads that move down and when the y is 0, i add another image on top of it, i tried to detect whether the image if off of the screen and remove it from the list, just so the list doesnt contain a billion characters. My code:

```
for i in range(len(lanes_y)):
        #increases the y of every image
        lanes_y[i] += 1
        #if the y is 0 we add a new image on top of the image
        if lanes_y[i] == 0:
            lanes_y.append(lanes_y[i] - 500)
        #if one of the images is less then 500 i remove it from the list to reduce lag
        if lanes_y[i] >= 500:
            lanes_y.pop(i)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating

Comment: TL;DR - never try to remove the list items while the program is looping... Bad and Dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

what is happening you are changing your list in the middle of execution with the command `lanes_y.pop(i)`
there for the length of the list changes in runtime:

```py
l = [1,2,3,4]

for i in range(len(l)):
    if i ==2:
        l.pop(i)
     print(len(l))
```

the output will be:

```
4
4
3
3
```

so in the final iteration when you are pointing at index 3 id dosent exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It is advised not to change the `list` while iterating over it.

However, you can remove or add elements, but you will have to update the value loop variable `i` accordingly:

```
lst = [i*i for i in range(5)]
# lst is [0, 1, 4, 9, 16]

for i in range(len(lst)):
  if i == 3:    
    lst.remove(9)
    # now lst becomes [0, 1, 4, 16]
    # so the index of next element is 3.
    # but the for loop will auto increment the i
    i -= 1    # it will cancel the effect of increment

  # do something with the lst[i]
  print(lst[i])
```